# AND array formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I know `AND` doesn't work as an array formula.

But does anyone know how could I make something like this with out the `AND`?

```
=ArrayFormula(AND(M2:M="CAD data",AG2:AG<>""))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use multiplication:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((M2:M="CAD data")*(AG2:AG<>""))
```